# What characters are safe in XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to send game result data as binary, partly for efficiency (sending 6 bytes per item instead of 13... that's more than halving the total amount of data to send, and as there can be a few hundred of these items, result is huge savings), and partly for obfuscation (people monitoring network activity would see seemingly random bytes instead of distinguishable data).

My "code" (not in use yet, just a prototype) is as follows:

```
String.fromCharCode.apply(null,somevar.toString(16).split(/(?=(?:..)+$)/).map(function(a) {return parseInt(a,16);}))
```

This will convert any integer value into a binary string value.

However, I seem to recall that AJAX and binary data don't mix. I'd like to know what range of values is safe to use. Should I stick to the range 32-255, or go even safer and stick to 32-127? In the case of 32-255, I can use 15 as the base in the above code and add 32 to all the numbers, so that'dw work for me.

But really I'm more interested in the character range question, and if there is any cross-browser (among browsers that support Canvas) way to transfer binary data?

Comment: [The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send()-method) says that strings *should* be converted to Unicode and then encoded as UTF-8. The only "raw" container is `ArrayBuffer`, which isn't supported by all browsers.

Comment: You can [send](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#send()) `ArrayBuffer`s just like you can send `Blob`s (Files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX and binary data does not conflict with each other. What happens is, when you make AJAX call, the data are posted as form data. When you post form data, you would usually encode the form data as application/x-www-form-url-encode. The encoded data only contain letters/numbers and certain special characters. For example, space is encoded as %20. For this reason, it may not save you any space at all even if you convert your "normal" letters to binary because eventually everything has to be encoded again.

Comment: Fair enough, although this doesn't really answer my question :p Out of curiosity, though, would `JSON.stringify` handle it properly?

Comment: "Binary data" covers *every* character possible.